# Azure: Retrieving 'address_space' in virtual_network class using Python script

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

I'm trying to create a script that will retrieve all the details of a specific VNET in Azure. Below is my python script:

```
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient

subscription_id = input("Enter the subscription ID where VNET is located: ")
rg_name = input("Enter the resource group where VNET is located: ")
vnet_name = input("Enter the VNET name: ")

credential = AzureCliCredential()
network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credential, subscription_id)

vnet = network_client.virtual_networks.get(rg_name, vnet_name)
print(vnet)
```

And below is the output:

```
{'additional_properties': {},'id': 'XXXXXXXXX', 'name': 'XXXXXXXXX', 'type': 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'location': 'southeastasia', 'tags': {'owner': 'test', 'dept': 'test-dept'}, 'extended_location': None, 'etag': 'XXXXXXXXX', 'address_space': <azure.mgmt.network.v2021_02_01.models._models_py3.AddressSpace object at 0x000002BC6E1F3C40>, 'dhcp_options': None, 'flow_timeout_in_minutes': None, 'subnets': [<azure.mgmt.network.v2021_02_01.models._models_py3.Subnet object at 0x000002BC6E1F3C70>, <azure.mgmt.network.v2021_02_01.models._models_py3.Subnet object at 0x000002BC6E1F3CA0>, <azure.mgmt.network.v2021_02_01.models._models_py3.Subnet object at 0x000002BC6E1F3CD0>], 'virtual_network_peerings': [], 'resource_guid': 'XXXXXXXXX', 'provisioning_state': 'Succeeded', 'enable_ddos_protection': False, 'enable_vm_protection': None, 'ddos_protection_plan': None, 'bgp_communities': None, 'ip_allocations': None}
```

As you can see, it displays **'address_space': <azure.mgmt.network.v2021_02_01.models._models_py3.AddressSpace object at 0x000002BC6E1F3C40>,** instead of an IP Address.

I have tried to import AddressSpace using:

```
from azure.mgmt.network.v2021_02_01.models._models_py3 import AddressSpace
```

But I can't seem to figure out how it works.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? Please let me know if you have any responses.

Answer (score 0):

I think we just need to play Apex Legends and reach the Predator rank, after that this code will work.

Answer (score 0):

The code is no problem, what you need to do is to explore deeper  in the address space property like this:

```
address_space = vnet.address_space.address_prefixes
print(address_space)
```

Get more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-network/azure.mgmt.network.v2020_06_01.models.addressspace?view=azure-python) about the return info of the get function of the network.